JupyterLab - Voila command is not creating the plot
I have the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interactive, widgets
from IPython.display import display

def plot_sine_wave(frequency, amplitude):
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 1000)
    y = amplitude * np.sin(frequency*x)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()



frequency_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=1.0, min=0.1, max=10.0, step=0.1, description='Frequency')
amplitude_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=1.0, min=0.1, max=10.0, step=0.1, description='Amplitude')
interactive_plot = interactive(plot_sine_wave, frequency=frequency_slider, amplitude=amplitude_slider)

display(interactive_plot)

and the output is:

but when I run
voila myjupter.ipynb there is no output, only:

Is something else which I can try?

It seems like you may have an environment issue. Does other ipywidgets examples work for you? Your code works fine in Voila. I can show you it working: Go to here and click on the launch badge under 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode in JupyterLab full-featured mode:' or just click here to launch direct. When the remote session comes up eventually, click the blue plus in the upper left ...

 open a new notebook & paste in your code. Then click on the Voila icon along the top middle of the ribbon toolbar just above the notebook. (The Voila icon looks like a squiggly yellow line above a green line.) That will open the Voila render and you'll see the plot. I have a very similar plot already working in Voila that you launch direct in Voila itself by clicking here. It is in notebooks/matplotlib_widget_control.ipynb at that repo I linked.

@Wayne, thank you for your input.
"Then click on the Voila icon[...]" -> I have already did it and it seems it is working, but when I run voila command there is no output, only the information from the second picture from my question...

Yes, so what you are now saying in your last comment is that it is a general issue with your environment, as I first stated. So make a new post because this one focuses on plotting. That is not the issue. Your Voila doesn't work or ipywidgets or matplotlib. Make it all simpler and don't stress the particular code you provide as much. Check the logs where you launch from. Does it indicate anything not quite working? See here for other troubleshooting ideas.
